# Update a text file in the raw folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an application reading a text file that is in the res/raw folder. It works great, but when I change this text file and try to run again the application on Eclipse (I don't need to change the raw file from this application, this I have seen that it is impossible. I just want to do it from Eclipse as I am still in the building phase of my application) and test it on my phony, the text file doesn't take into account the modifications.
The only way I found to update the file in the application is to uninstall it and re-run it.

Is it normal? Is there no way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed, it was happening in the Searchable Dictionary (sample application from Android), the fix is simply to increment the database version when it's changed, and it will automatically load it again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, eclipse did not know it was updated, so

```
Right click on a project -> refresh.
```

If that does not help try

```
Project -> Clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a default behavior.

Assuming you dragged a file named "ABC.txt" from D drive inside the raw folder of your project. Project worspace is in E drive.

Once you drag and drop, a new file will be created in E drive inside your application folder. This file is different from the one in D drive.

Comment: I am not sure to follow. Also, when I open this "ABC.txt" file from Eclipse the modifications are there, so why not on the app? You are saying there is no other way than reinstalling the application?

Comment: How did you make the modifications? My point is when you modify the file from the location where you dragged, those changes will not get reflected. If you are modifying it through application or in eclipse, it should be present.

Comment: Please add some clarification on how you are modifying the file.

Comment: I can't modify it from Eclipse because it doesn't open it properly. I use special characters such as ó ę ą and if I open the txt file in Eclipse they turn out as Ä™, Å¼, etc. So I just wrote "test" somewhere opening the file from its location outside the project. I can see the "test" when opening the txt file in Eclipse (despite the wrong encoding of the special characters), but not in the app when I build it